# Cakephp 3.x translating the routes

Tags: cakephp, routes, internationalization, cakephp-3.0

is there a way to transtate the routes?
For example:

```
domain.com/catalog/products     // english
domain.com/catalogo/productos   // portuguese
```

two different routes, but calling the same Plugin/Controller/Action/

I tried creating like this:

```
    Router::plugin('Catalog', ['path' => __d('catalog', /catalog']), function ($routes ){
        $routes->connect(__d('catalog','/inventory'),
            ['controller' => 'inventory', 'action' => 'index']
        );
    }
```

But, the `I18n::locale()` return EVERYTIME the default "en_US" even if my user who is logged on my site is "pt_BR".
On my controller, the same function: `I18n::locale()` returns right.

Ok, now let's imagine that's impossible to do this "automatically" with `__d()` and I have to write every route in every language (at least at the moment it's just 2).

So, how can I create the links according by the language of the user?
for example:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
        __d('catalog','inventory'),
        ['plugin'=>'catalog', 'controller' => 'inventory', 'action' => 'index']
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

> But, the I18n::locale() return EVERYTIME the default "en_US" even if my user who is logged on my site is "pt_BR". On my controller, the same function: I18n::locale() returns right.

Sounds like an issue with the execution order. Go figure out when the language is actually set. I'm not sure nor do I have the mood and time right now to look it up for you, but I think that the routes are loaded even before the apps bootstrap.php.

Depending on how you implemented your language detection I guess it's set after your routes and that's the reason why you end up with en_US. If you're using the language dispatcher filter I guess it is set after the routes but logically before the controller gets loaded.

Comment: I tried to put I18n::locale("pt_BR") on bootstrap.php even though on my routes was return en_US, the default. And bootstrap.php loads first than routes.php. But this problem I can create hardcode, setting every route in every language.
But the main problem is how to create a url depending on the language.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? It seems like routes are loaded way before bootstrap.